# Problems manipulating JSON data in PHP

Tags: php, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm not that handy with JSON so here goes. I'm receiving Amazon SNS notifications for bouncing email addresses to a listener (in PHP 5.5) which does:

```
    $post = @file_get_contents("php://input");
    $object = json_decode($post, true);
```

This gives me:

```
Type => Notification
MessageId => #####
TopicArn => #####
Message => {
    "notificationType":"Bounce",
    "bounce": {
        "bounceSubType":"General",
        "bounceType":"Permanent",
        "bouncedRecipients":[{"status":"5.3.0","action":"failed","diagnosticCode":"smtp; 554 delivery error: dd This user doesn't have a yahoo.com account (testuser@yahoo.com) [0] - mta1217.mail.bf1.yahoo.com","emailAddress":"testuser@yahoo.com"}],
        "reportingMTA":"dsn; ######",
        "timestamp":"2014-10-27T16:37:42.136Z",
        "feedbackId":"######"
    },
    "mail": {
        "timestamp":"2014-10-27T16:37:40.000Z",
        "source":"myemail@mydomain.com",
        "messageId":"######",
        "destination":["testuser@yahoo.com"]
    }
}
```

I was expecting an associative array all the way down but instead it's an array only at the top level and with JSON strings inside. I've tried everything I can think of, including json_decoding further parts of the array, but I'm struggling to access the data in a simple way. What I need is the "destination" email address which should be in `$object['Message']['mail']['destination'][0]`.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: Are you doing a print_r of $object?  Can you show what var_dump($object) gives you instead?  It might make things more clearer.

Comment: @Phil_1984_: It's a listener that receives the JSON directly from Amazon so I'm not able to var_dump. I can write the output into a text file for debugging. I don't anything built at the moment to simulate an Amazon request and run it in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like $object['Message'] is also json encoded.  Perhaps because it's using some generic container format for service call results.  Try this

```
$post = @file_get_contents("php://input");
$object = json_decode($post, true);
//Message contains a json string
$object['Message'] = json_decode($object['Message'], true);
//Then access the structure using array notation
echo $object['Message']['mail']['destination'][0];
```

Comment: Crazy, but this works. Looks like I'll have to json_decode a few times to get down all the way. I tried this but I think I must have missed the true flag to force it to an array. Thanks! I've spent too much time on this.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use json_decode at every level.  The Message part is just double encoded.  Yes the true parameter is important, otherwise you'll get objects.  I will update my answer to show how to access your example variable.

Comment: You're right. It's encoded only twice and after that it can be accessed as an array. It's working perfectly now. Thanks again.